# Disable user to type the date field in reactJS for date field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started project with ReactJS and I have implemented an html date field . I wanted the date field to be disabled for users to edit . Only he can select the date from the datepicker.
I saw in some places where `onkeydown = "return false"` will work. 
Since I am using reactJS, how can I make use of this feature.

```
export default observer(({ field, type = 'date', readOnly = false }) => {
...
<div className="form__input-group">
                <input
                    className="form_date"
                    id={field.id}
                    min={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                    aria-describedby="name-desc"
                    {...field.bind({ type })}
                    readOnly={readOnly}
                />
            </div>
...
}
```

When I hardcode `onkeydown = "return false"` in the developer console it works. How can I make it from the jsx ? Can somebody please help

Comment: Why don't you just set the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: why did you tag angularjs?